# Kerne module for Oracle 11gR2 RAC on Linux

Tags: oracle, linux, oracle-asm

As per Oracle, it requires three Linux packages to run `ASMLib`:

1. `oracleasm` - kernel module
2. `oracleasmlib-2.0` - ASMLib libraries
3. `oracleasm-support-2.0` - Admin for ASMLib

This library versions are OS dependent, but my RAC is working fine without the `oracleasm`  kernel module.

```
 $ rpm -qa | grep 'oracleasm'
oracleasm-support-2.1.8-1.el6.i686
oracleasmlib-2.0.4-1.el6.i686
```

And

```
$ oracleasm listdisks
DB_DISK1
DB_DISK2
FRA_DISK1
FRA_DISK2
OCR_VOTE1
OCR_VOTE2
OCR_VOTE3
```

Someone can please guide why its running perfectly without having main kernel module?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what kernel you're running, I can't say for sure, but my guess is that you're running a recent UEK kernel, and it has the kernel module built in.

Comment: Linux kernel is: # cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.39-400.17.1.el6uek.i686 (mockbuild@ca-build44.us.oracle.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Feb 22 18:17:46 PST 2013              I want to use tagging to make post appear good but not able to understand how to use, please guide me.

Comment: Yes, see the 'uek' in the kernel string?  That means it's a UEK kernel.  (Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel)  That's a kernel put together by Oracle, with Oracle's patches and additions, which includes the ASMLib kernel driver.